# Jquery UI draggable - Using percents instead of pixels

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

i have a problem with jq-ui draggable.

I drag a DIV (on my home PC 1680x1024) into the right/bottom corner and save the position (left:125px; top:1536px;). 
Everything works fine. But when i switch to my netbook (1024x768) i get a stupid scrollbar. The problem is the different Screensize.

Is it possible to use percents instead of pixels on jquery ui draggable() und resizeable()?

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate the percentage of the total screen resolution for your my home PC 1680x1024 and position (left:125px; top:1536px;) it will be width: 125/1680 * 100 and height:  1536/1024 * 100 and then wen showing the DIV in laptop calculate the new position based on these percentages.

P.S. I am not sure that the position that you are have said is correct top should be less than 1024 (your monitor height).

Answer (score 2):

Try this one :

```
$("element").draggable({
    stop: function (){
     var l = ( 100 * parseFloat($(this).css("left")) / parseFloat($(this).parent().css("width")) )+ "%" ;
     var t = ( 100 * parseFloat($(this).css("top")) / parseFloat($(this).parent().css("height")) )+ "%" ;
     $(this).css("left" , l);
     $(this).css("top" , t);
     }

});
```

Comment: Works nicely if parent has some computed height&width, however maybe I would suggest to rather use `position().left/top` instead of `css("left/top")` and `width/height()` instead of `css("width/height")`